# Type mismatch error when trying to format float variable inside string interpolator

Tags: scala

[image]

Currently, I am learning Scala Language and trying to find out the ways to print the variable without using the plus *(`+`)* operator in `println()` or `print()` methods, and rather using the  **String Interpolation** technique.
So now I got some error. when trying to add a float value using `${num2:.2f}` in the third example.

#### Output I want :

`10 --- 10.25 --- Hello world` in all cases.

The 1st and 2nd cases give me that kind of output, but not in the third case. That's why I wrote it as `${num2:.2f}` but it gives me an error.

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val num1: Int = 10
    val num2: Float = 10.2543f
    val str1: String = "Hello world"

    //    1st way
    printf("%d --- %.2f --- %s\n", num1, num2, str1)

    //    2nd way
    println("%d --- %.2f --- %s".format(num1, num2, str1))

    //    3rd way
    println(s"$num1 --- ${num2:.2f} --- $str1")
  }
```

Error:

> Type Mismatch Error:
> s"${num2:.2f}"
> Found:    (num2 : Float)
> Required: (0.2f : Float)

###### Please help me to solve this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> s"$num1 --- ${num2:.2f} --- $str1"

Not sure from where you thought that would be valid.
At first glance, it even seems like invalid syntax *(although is valid, but means something different of what you want)*.

Anyways, if we check the [official docs on **String interpolation**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-f-interpolator) we can see that the right way to do that is:

```scala
f"$num1 --- $num2%.2f --- $str1"
// val res: String = "10 --- 10.25 --- Hello world"
```

---

> ${num2:.2f}

*This actually means that we are trying to upcast `num2` to the type `0.2f`; which is the literal type of the literal value `0.2f`, but, of course, that fails*.

Comment: this line worked for me `println(f"$num1%d --- $num2%.2f --- $str1%s")`, thank you again.